# Masking the columns of pytorch matrix

Tags: matrix, pytorch, mask, tensor, binary-matrix

I have a matrix of shape `(batch_size, N, N)` and a masking tensor of shape `(batch_size, N)`.

I want to put -infinity values only for the columns (and not rows) of the matrix, according to the given mask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is via repeating the mask in the correct dimension:

```
repeated_mask[mask.unsqueeze(-1).repeat(1,1,mask.shape[-1])!=1] = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can use [`torch.Tensor.expand_as`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Tensor.expand_as.html):

```
>>> x[m[...,None].expand_as(x)]
```